# Array Questions & Problems

Tags: c#, arrays

First and foremost I'm a complete beginner at C# and I'm currently attending a beginners class. To keep it short, one of my assignments given to me is quite complex to me and I'm having a lot of trouble understanding arrays with returning values, and a few other various problems which I'll leave for later.

So my problem at the moment is that in short I'm trying to get an array to SUM all of its contents (double price) of a list of items (a restaurant bill) then on top of that I'm trying to get that said SUM to be converted to a double value. Like "NetAmount" for instance. From there I need to be able to use "NetAmount" as a regular double to be able to 1. Give the final bill with tax, 2. Give a tip (either a dollar amount or percentage).

I've written as much code as possible, it's just this that I'm trying to fix.
Here is the PasteBin of the entire code:
 https://pastebin.com/qp35dQtp

Part of the code I'm having trouble with:

```
 static double GetTip(double NetAmount, double GST)
    {
        double TotalBill = NetAmount + GST;
        double percentage, percentMulti, tipAmount, dollar, tipType;
        tipAmount = 1;
        percentage = 0;
        tipType = getPosInt("Enter Tip Type:");


        if (tipType == 1)
        {
            percentage = getPosDbl("Enter a whole number percentage");
            percentMulti = percentage / 100;
            tipAmount = TotalBill * percentMulti;

        }
        else if (tipType == 2)
        {
            dollar = getPosDbl("Enter dollar amount");
            tipAmount = dollar;

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error - Invalid input");
        }
        return tipAmount;
    }
```

If there's a way you guys would prefer me to paste code, just let me know. I figured this would be better than screenshots.

The issues I'm having are under the LIST and TIP arrays. My teacher had mentioned that I should use a separate an array for calculating all the GST, Net, and total amounts. But back again to not understanding how the return function works, not to mention all the errors whilst trying to use it (lol).

The code is a bit of a mess right now, I'll admit, but I'm honestly quite overwhelmed and stressed that this single part of the code is stopping me from submitting my assignment.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? If you're using Visual Studio (and assuming you're on windows), you can set a breakpoint with `F9` and press `F5` to debug. Code execution will pause (or "break") when it reaches a breakpoint, allowing you to mouse over variables and see their values. You can then press `F10` and `F11` to execute lines of code one at a time (called stepping). If you run your code this way, set a breakpoint at the first line of your function, and step through the lines one by one you may be able to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. There's no arrays in the code you have pasted here and looking through the Pastebin link there's a large amount of code. Do what E. Moffat suggests and debug your code to find any issues and try and refine your question to be a bit more specific.

Comment: After reading your question, it seems like your problem is that you cannot see the tip amount displayed on the screen. Is that correct?

Comment: @TejSoft Yes and no, the tip display problem is one part and the other part is trying to get a reference value from either a percentage or dollar amount entered.

Comment: @Steve Unless I'm mistaken, isn't "static double GetTip(double NetAmount, double GST)" part of an array? and my apologies, being so new with coding is hard to explain my issue. My now new issue is trying to get "tipAmount" to be displayed, and I'm struggling to get it to return a value other than "0" as it keeps giving me an error unless I state the value of the code somewhere. Ex. " tipAmount = 1;" or "dollar = 0;" then onward from there, trying to get it to display on the console.

Comment: @E.Moffat I know about debugging but that's not the issue here, I'm just having trouble with understanding how to pull a variable out from where it says "return tipAmount;". As I mentioned to Steve, it's always returning a 0 value unless I declare the value itself somewhere which is causing conflicts. It's forcing me to put "tipAmount = 0;" despite having the user enter a value for either a percentage or dollar amount.

Comment: @KieranMasters arrays in C# are marked with `[]` or other generic classes like `List`. Your method has multiple parameters and returns a single value. What error are you getting?

Comment: @Steve Ah I gotcha, thank you. For the errors, I've fixed them for now, however a new issue arrives! The first is finding out how to sum an array ( price[] ) and to be able to use price[] and do something funky like NetAmount = price[]. The second problem is getting the 3 arrays I have to display them in a list which would be a "bubble sort" method that I'm working on. If that all makes sense?

Comment: Bump - Still having problems. I did however find out that I need to loop the array to sum it. However the array always returns a 0 value for some reason.